# Why is my prototype function not updating? (C)

Tags: c

I am having some trouble with my prototype function in C. It is supposed to be updating so eventually the whole array is filled with 'C's. However, it keeps on resetting every time it called so there is only 1 'C' on the board at most. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

**Also, a is a flag, that if 1 the area should display a 'C' in location [b][c].

```
void UpdateMap(a,b,c){

    int i,j;
    char showlist[MAP][MAP];

    if (a==1){
        showlist[b][c]='C';
    }

    for(i=0;i<MAP;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (j=0;j<MAP;j++){
            if (showlist[i][j]!='C'){
                showlist[i][j]='-';
            }

            printf("%c\t", showlist[i][j]);

    }
}
}
```

Edit: Sorry very new to programming and this website. So not sure if I'm responding in the right area or if anyone will see this.

Anyhow I changed my showlist[MAP][MAP] to Nshowlist[MAP][MAP] since from my understanding it would create problems if I had another showlist[MAP][MAP] in main.

SO in my function prototypes (I dont understand how this term is wrong?) I have:

In main, it is calling it:
UpdateMap(section[l-1][m-1].playerOwns, l-1,m-1, Nshowlist[MAP][MAP]);

And then what I previously posted is changed to:
void UpdateMap(int a,int b, int c, char Nshowlist[MAP][MAP]){

```
int i,j;
```

But now it stops working? Can someone tell me why? 
void UpdateMap(int a,int b,int c,char Nshowlist[MAP][MAP]);

Comment: make `char showlist[MAP][MAP];` global because else it's recreated each time you're calling the function. resetting at each call is expected!

Comment: I don't think "prototype" means what you think it means.

Comment: No, don't use globals.

Comment: okay, or pass your double array as a parameter.

Comment: Where are the types of your function parameters?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** write K&R-style function definitions.  You should only ever write a full prototype for the function definition or declaration — like `void UpdateMap(int a, int b, int c)` — with the types of the arguments explicitly specified in the argument list.  The style you're using was marked obsolescent in C90 and is technically not a part of C99 or beyond (though compilers still allow it for reasons of backwards compatibility).

Comment: If you want the `showlist` array to be preserved over multiple (all) calls to your function then you could declare it `static`.

Comment: Since the function creates the array each time it is called, your current design won't work.  Further, only the one cell has a defined value; all the rest are garbage.  You need to allocate the array outside the function and pass it in as an extra argument.  You could go 'grubby' and use a global variable instead — don't do that though, unless there's a really good reason.

Comment: I have the types at the beginning of my function and now I editted it and added them in.

Answer (score 1):

since `char showlist[MAP][MAP];` is declared locally, it is allocated as an auto variable and there's no guarantee that you get the data you put in it in the previous call: it's *undefined behaviour*.

You have to extend the lifespan of this variable, for instance by declaring outside your function and pass it as a parameter. My proposal (with other paramters as `int`, since you used legacy way of declaring them, which isn't recommended)

```
void UpdateMap(int a,int b,int c,char showlist[MAP][MAP]){

    int i,j;
```

Then declare

```
char showlist[MAP][MAP];
```

somewhere in your caller, and pass `showlist` as last parameter of your function. The `showlist` variable has now a lifespan outside the function, and the memory of the previous calls is kept (provided you don't do the same local declaration in a caller that's called by another upper routine of course!)